# Getting Tweet ID of a particular tweet

Tags: php, twitter

On my site I've added a Tweet button. What I want to do is whenever user clicks on that button and the tweet gets posted on user's twitter account, I want to catch the unique id of that tweet and store it into the database.
Is it possible to do that using PHP??

Answer (score 1):

When calling the REST API (`http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json` -- or whichever format), you get back the ID string.  However, it also implies that you must route everything through your server using oAuth.

Alternatively, you could use the JavaScript API, along with one of the official Twitter JS widgets, and create an event listener to catch the `tweet` event.  From there, you should have appropriate information in the data field of the event (something like evt.data), which you could pass to your server through AJAX.

JS Docs:  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events

REST Docs:  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Comment: using their javascript api, I'm getting event.data returned as null. have you actually successfully pulled any relevant information using the tweet binding mechanism? if so, can you describe how you did it? I have no problem pulling event.data when binding follow.