# Getting Tweet id

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Tweet ID of a particular tweet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678403/getting-tweet-id-of-a-particular-tweet)

On my site I've added a Tweet button. What I want to do is whenever user clicks on that button and the tweet gets posted on user's twitter account, I want to catch the unique id of that tweet and store it into the database.

Comment: so what have you done to achieve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678403/getting-tweet-id-of-a-particular-tweet seems to me that you are asking the same question on multiple accounts.

Comment: For the 1st time i am posting this question.donn't have multiple accounts

Answer (score 0):

The tweet id should be in the callback...

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update

What's at the bottom is what is returned to you.

Comment: I am not getting the tweet id in return.using configurable tweet box in which i am holding the callbacik parameters in th onTweet() function.Can you please suggest how can i get the tweet id

Comment: The only way you can get the tweet id is an user authenticates via your app and gives you permission to post the tweet on his behalf.
Then you get a call back with the tweet id.
No other solution really...